# How to read last event in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

my app is divided as follows:

Product List Page and Product Page.

When I scroll through the product list page and click on a product by going to the product page and then go back to the product list page, I lose the scroll position and the products are re-loaded with another order from server.

I was looking for a way to save the scroll position and the loaded products on the product list page when I go back from the product page.

I tried to insert my `<router-view>` inside `<keep-alive>` but I don't like how it works. The old data is displayed before the new one.

Then i tried to save the products and the scroll position in vuex, this works, but, when I go back, the products are remapped from the store and not cached, so if the page is not completely loaded the scroll does not return to the exact point. I'm using a timeout for "solving" this problem.

```
//inside listing products page

    mounted() { 
        EventBus.$emit('listingLoaded');
    }

//inside router
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {

        if (savedPosition && EventBus.$on('listingLoaded', ()=>{})){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve(savedPosition)
                    }, 5000)
                }
            )
        } else return { x: 0, y: 0 };

    }
```

I dont want to use a timeout, I would need a way to catch the last listingLoaded event or cache the previous page.

**In redux-saga i used takeLatest to take the last action, what i can do with vue?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to handle the scroll yourself rather than Vue-Router.

Comment: @IVOGELOV how? I can save position in store, but its' the same.. i need to trigged this action or event after that products are loaded 100%

Comment: Exactly - you need to save the current scroll position in `router.beforeEach` hook and then, after you load all products - **you** need to manually scroll to the saved position (probably inside `$nextTick` - to be sure that all products are rendered in DOM).

Comment: @IVOGELOV its the same, the position is saved in scrollBehavior, i tried to trigger the events inside update but this don't resolve my problem.. so.. how i can cache the previous page?

Comment: You misunderstood me. Your current solution is to use `scrollBehavior` inside the router - and it does not work. Your new solution should be to remove this function from your code and instead perform `window.scrollTo(0, oldY)` immediately after you load **all** products back.